# How can Windows move a newly compressed file so fast across different disks

Tags: windows, windows-10, filesystems, file-transfer

Disk 1: HDD, non-OS disk 
Disk 2: SSD, non-OS disk

On Disk 1, I compress a 2 GB folder with 1000+ files into a zip file (no-compression mode). 
Then I move the zip file from Disk 1 to Disk 2. The system finishes the operation in less than 1 second.

Edit: as per the request from the comments, the resulting zip file is also ~2GB in size.

Also, as @DrMoishe Pippik mentioned, 2GB can fit into the memory, with the fact that NVME SSDs can reach a writing speed of 6900 MB/s, is it possible, that the compression operation left the zipped file in the memory, which is then being used when it is copied to SSD? Is Windows that smart?

Comment: *The system finishes the operation in less than 1 second* It doesn't unless the resulting file is very small. Please check the ZIP file's actual size. What it contains and the compression method is irrelevant here. Please [edit] the question to provide useful info, thank you.

Comment: 2 GB folder is a meaningless value in this story. What counts is actual size on disk and what counts is actual size of the resulting ZIP file. Which TBH seems rather obvious to me and information you'd include when asking this type of question.

Comment: 1. 2 GB is small enough to fit entirely in memory, so can be moved in one swell foop. A test with 20 2 GB files, or one 40 GB file, might be **far** slower. 2. There is caching both on SSD and HDD drives and in the OS, so the operation may appear to have completed while still being written.